# How to pass url param through amazon cognito hosted login

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am using Amazon Cognito hosted login for my webapp and everything has been working great.  However, today I decided I wanted to pass a urlParam through the login flow.  The desired behavior is that a user goes to
`https://example.com/?param1=foo`
if they aren't logged in they go to the hosted cognito login page and when they go through the login flow and return to my site they go back to
`https://example.com/?param1=foo.`

Unfortunately, if I try to add the ?param1=foo to the redirect_uri url param for the hosted login flow, I get an error like this, "error?error=redirect_mismatch" on the cognito signin page.

Is there some way to set the callback url to allow for a url param?  Or is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that you need to do this via the "state" parameter.

In your ```https://example.amazoncognito.com/''' you need a &state= with whatever information you want and that will flow through the redirect uri (as a state= uri param) that you can then read.

This also requires that you have the latest version of the SDK (1.1.2 or greater).  See this issue: https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-auth-js/issues/58.

Comment: Do you have an example of this?

Comment: Can you provide a working example of this?